# extracting data from json string returns an error

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, json

I'm having this code in a php file

```
[
{
    "_id": "549f065925e1928098c74275",
    "index": 0,
    "guid": "c21b3720-430e-4be3-9309-e8afbabc0020",
    "email": "browningriley@zilodyne.com",
    "phone": "+1 (804) 417-2615",
    "address": "657 Temple Court, Katonah, Mississippi, 7139",
    "about": "Ut laborum ut nostrud dolore ut aute irure aliquip duis. Amet proident fugiat cupidatat nulla ullamco adipisicing ea excepteur. Proident in ullamco aute reprehenderit ea. Consequat non cupidatat id sit nostrud non. Velit amet exercitation incididunt aliqua deserunt cupidatat et ex.\r\n",
    "registered": "2014-09-05T01:48:12 -03:00",
    "latitude": -44.882099,
    "longitude": 24.574332,
    "tags": [
        "officia",
        "consectetur",
        "incididunt",
        "eu",
        "magna",
        "esse",
        "elit"
    ],
    "friends": [
        {
            "id": 0,
            "name": "Billie Jarvis"
        },
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Laurie Espinoza"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "Kate Stuart"
        }
    ],
    "greeting": "Hello, Browning Riley! You have 6 unread messages.",
    "favoriteFruit": "banana"
},
{
    "_id": "549f065925aa17df2fd6ebea",
    "index": 1,
    "guid": "9cf247e8-fe6b-4c42-a4a3-24ef7b907ad4",
    "email": "bonitasharp@medalert.com",
    "phone": "+1 (946) 506-2141",
    "address": "414 Willoughby Avenue, Gila, California, 4696",
    "about": "Aliqua aute tempor veniam sit esse velit anim. Proident amet aliqua ad non labore eu voluptate labore in amet exercitation irure. Qui laborum ea aliqua consectetur minim aliqua amet minim laborum sint fugiat ullamco nulla elit.\r\n",
    "registered": "2014-02-11T20:29:39 -02:00",
    "latitude": -19.03677,
    "longitude": 138.137275,
    "tags": [
        "eu",
        "non",
        "et",
        "nostrud",
        "enim",
        "proident",
        "sint"
    ],
    "friends": [
        {
            "id": 0,
            "name": "Gamble Porter"
        },
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Jami Bell"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "Mullen Alexander"
        }
    ],
    "greeting": "Hello, Bonita Sharp! You have 5 unread messages.",
    "favoriteFruit": "strawberry"
}
]
```

Now trying to extract data from this string as follows

```
 $("#get").on('click',function(){

            $.get('data.php',function(data){
                console.log(data);
                var json_array = data;
                var new_array = [];
                $.each(json_array,function(i,o) {
                 new_array.push(o._id);
                });

                console.log(new_array);

        });
    });
```

But this is the result "TypeError: invalid 'in' operand a" as you can see here [in this online example](http://plnkr.co/edit/ZDIq48RauhOBFT0kuden?p=preview). the php file is data.php and the code is in the script.js file

Comment: I sincerely hope that that information is not real data of actual people!

Comment: no it's from here http://www.json-generator.com/ just random not real json data

Comment: Use `$.getJSON` instead of `$.get`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you need to do is set the `dataType` as `'json'` or use `$.getJSON()` which sets the dataType automatically.

This will tell `$.ajax` what to expect and to parse it accordingly

```
     $.get('data.php',function(data){

                var myarray = data;
                console.log(myarray);
                var new_array = [];
                $.each(myarray,function(i,o) {
                 new_array.push(o._id);
                });

                console.log(new_array);


            $("#result").text(new_array);
        },'json');/* last argument is "dataType" */
```

The content header for the file is not being sent as `application/json`

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/2fPSsPmF1liA7HNQEwM4?p=preview)**</kbd>

Answer (score 2):

You need to parse your php response:
`data = JSON.parse(data)`
 See this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/CZVezyGSZgamp3DPFAoZ?p=preview) (line 7 was updated)

The reason is that you are getting a string in the response, then you need to parse it to JSON, you do so by the above example.

Comment: the benefit of letting jQuery do the parsing internally is you don't need to create your own try/catch in case  of invalid json string rather it will trigger an ajax error callback instead

Comment: @charlietfl, you are right but it is better to understand what is going on behind jquery (little of it)

Comment: but that's part of my point, using the internals to help catch errors without having to catch them yourself. Your solution doesn't cover the extra error handling that would be needed